# Matlab: Convert string to cell

Tags: matlab

How to convert a string, containing a cell to a cell, fx:

```
astring='{1,[2,3,4],''bla''}'
```

To what i want:

```
a1x3cell={1,[2,3,4],'bla'}
```

The problem arises when using: Uicontrol: style "edit", which outputs the input value as a string, ie. converts input:

```
{1,[2,3,4],'bla'}
```

to output:

```
'{1,[2,3,4],''bla''}'
```

Comment: `a = eval(astring)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

Either use `eval`, as suggested by @Divakar

```
a = eval(string)
```

Or convert the string to an anonymous function and evaluate that

```
fun = str2func(['@()',string]);
a = fun()
```